# Compatibility of Dura Ace SL-BS79 bar end shifters with GRX RX400 derailleur

Tags: shimano, shifter, compatibility, grx

Are road 10s 2x10 Dura Ace SL-BS79 bar-end shifters compatible with gravel GRX RX400 derailleurs 2x10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GRX 400 derives from Tiagra 4700, that uses different pull ratios than other 10-speed systems from Shimano. So it's not compatible.

Comment: *If* the SL-BS79 shifters have a friction-only mode in addition to their indexed mode, *and* they can provide enough total cable pull to move the GRX 400 RD through its full range, they'd work.  But I can't seem to find detailed-enough specs for the SL-BS79 from Shimano's archive.

Comment: According to my experience and this topic BS79 has no friction mode: https://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/548931-shimano-dura-ace-bs79-bar-end-shifters-no-friction-index.html